# What is the Ruby expression execute priority with the multiply method chain together?

Tags: ruby

What the ruby actually does for the following statement

```
"one" << "two" + "three"
```

is

```
("one" << "two") + "three"
```

or

```
"one" << ("two" + "three")
```

Does some methods like `*` that have high priority than others like `+`, the same as it behaves in mathematic? or just is evaluated from left to right?

Comment: Determining *if* there's precedence is easy; from irb type `1 + 2 * 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` will be first operator. Full operator precedence table can be found [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence).